# How to get less-than-equal-to to show in iTextRenderer conversion

Tags: java, pdf, xhtml, itext, flying-saucer

I've tried everything I know but still cannot get the ≥ and ≤ characters to show up in my PDF generated by Flying Saucer's iTextRenderer from xHTML.  They display fine in my browser as HTML of course.  I've tried different xml encoding types, doctypes, and using the decimal and hex values instead of the shortcut names.  Still, no errors display, but I get a blank space where the characters should be.

Has anyone successfully converted an xhtml to pdf using iTextRenderer with the ≤ and ≥ special symbols, and if so, how?

SOLUTION:  Okay, I got this one solved.  Turns out I did need to embed the Verdana font into the PDF using the follow lines of Java code:

```
renderer.getFontResolver().addFont("/Library/Fonts/Verdana.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
renderer.getFontResolver().addFont("/Library/Fonts/Verdana Bold.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
renderer.getFontResolver().addFont("/Library/Fonts/Verdana Italic.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
renderer.getFontResolver().addFont("/Library/Fonts/Verdana Bold Italic.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
```

Comment: have you tried prefixing it with with \ i.e: \≤

Comment: maybe the gliph in not included in the font you are using?

Comment: As for the glyph and font, how can I tell what symbols are supported by what fonts and do I need to do anything on the Java side to include the font in the PDF?

Comment: just open the font in a character map and search if the gliphs are present; or try another font to see if the problem persists

Comment: Okay, I got this one solved.  Turns out I did need to embed the Verdana font into the PDF.  I'll try and show the solution above as an edit to the original question.  Thanks everyone for the tips!

Comment: @BradG. better yet - post it as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLUTION: Okay, I got this one solved. Turns out I did need to embed the Verdana font into the PDF using the follow lines of Java code:

```
renderer.getFontResolver().addFont("/Library/Fonts/Verdana.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
renderer.getFontResolver().addFont("/Library/Fonts/Verdana Bold.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
renderer.getFontResolver().addFont("/Library/Fonts/Verdana Italic.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
renderer.getFontResolver().addFont("/Library/Fonts/Verdana Bold Italic.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
```